# ColorAnimation does not trigger

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight

I try to animate the LinearGradientBrush of my template. I would like to change the color of the canvas background if a click has been performed. The "Pressed" event gets fired, but nothing happens.

```
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ButtonTemplate" TargetType="Button">
        <Grid>
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                        <Storyboard AutoReverse="True" Duration="0:0:0.5">
                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Form" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Background).(LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)" To="Red" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Form" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Background).(LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" From="Black" To="Red" Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled" />
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

            <Canvas Name="Form" Height="35">
                <Canvas.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,0.5" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF007FEA" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF004580" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Canvas.Background>
            </Canvas>

            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see an `x:Key` on there. If this is just a snip from your `Button` Style Template, then just remove that x:Key, however if this `ControlTemplate` is being used as a resource then you're just hitting the wrong TargetProperty since I'm pretty sure Canvas is `Panel.` and you can just replace the `Storyboard.TargetProperty` and lose the `From` attrib in the animation like shown in working `ColorAnimation`'s below.

```
<ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="Red" 
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[0].(GradientStop.Color)" 
                Storyboard.TargetName="Form"/>
<ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="Black" 
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" 
                Storyboard.TargetName="Form"/>
```

Comment: Yes, it is used as a StaticResource. And Panel.Background works. Thanks